# Install a VPN Server on Ubuntu or CentOS which is router compatible

Tags: linux, unix, networking, vpn, pptp

I am new to this networking stuff and for the last three days I have been trying to install PPTP VPN Server on my Ubuntu. Computers running XP can connect to it without a single problem, but when I try to connect the VPN Router (D-Link DIR-100) to it, it hangs on connecting.

At first, I thought it was a problem in my router, so I tried to connect `UnblockVPN`s VPN Network; this network was connected to the router successfully.

My question here is: If the router can connect to `UnblockVPN`, then why can't connect to mine ubuntu?
I followed this guys guide to setup a VPN on Ubuntu: http://blog.riobard.com/2011/11/12/pptp-vpn-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Please provide some code examples to deal with... It's hard to give advice on a way too abstract level...

Comment: Grammar mistakes fixed, and please don't vote in negative or I won't be able to ask a new question. It's a request

Comment: Well... It seems, you corrected one error I did while trying to improve your vague and poor quality question. That's fine, but it should as well prove to you, that your initial try to ask a specific question was from low quality. I tried my very best to make your question more readable. Sorry, I failed. And if you want to prevent being voted negative, please consider improving your question quality keeping the [quality standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) in mind. At least, you should be thankful, I tried to improve your question instead of flagging it for removal.

Comment: And now to help you getting an answer: Please double check your configuration files whether you did a mistake when following the mentioned guide. And you should post a comment on whether your double check was successful. If it was, it's best to provide some more configuration information of your actual server, so that other could check your configuration for you. Your question is still pretty unspecific...